# Intelijj does not prompt for any imports when programming in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, intellij-idea

I'm trying to code in React-Native. When I'm programming in intellij, it does not suggest any imports, for example react jsx elements. I believe intellij supports auto imports. please help.

[image: context menu in intelliJ]

Comment: please try installing `@types/react-native` (`npm i @types/react-native`) - does it help?

Comment: It works! Thanks!!!!!